# How do i take a number out of string and add 1 to it

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to create a Substring where i take the number in the Codes and add 1 to it unless its a 4 then i keep the same code.

Query
Case
When
Substring(Codes 3 for 1) =4
Then Codes
Else Substring (Codes from 3 for 1) +1
End New Lvl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psVnI.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images, just add the information to the post.

Comment: Is the number always in the same place? Can there be only 1 number? Is the string always the same length?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only codes from 1 to 4 at the 3rd position:

```
   Substring(Codes from 1 for 2)
|| Case Substring(Codes from 3 for 1)
     when '1' Then '2'
     when '2' Then '3'
     else '4'
   end 
|| Substring (Codes from 4)
```